# How to process instances of classes in parallel in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a variable number of instances of one class, normally 3. I would like to call the class functions in each iteration of an infinite loop. Currently it is working sequentially, meaning I call each member function after each other. I would like to parallelize that part. What do you recommend?

I tried to construct an `std::vector<std::thread>`. I could initialize the threads and call a function on them at initialization.

```
MyCustomClass my_class_instance();
std::thread one_thread(&MyCustomClass::init, &my_class_instance, "string");
threads_.push_back(std::move(one_thread));
```

But now I would like to get each thread of the vector threads and then to call the class member function. If it would be a `std::vector` of class instances I would just call: `vector.at(index).class_function()`. How do I do that for threads? Or is that not possible?

By the way, it is in C++.

Thanks

Comment: `Future` might be a way to achieve if you just need parallel operation.

Answer (score 1):

In c++11, speciy `std::launch::async` is one of your choice, if asynchronicity is essential for you.

There are two launch policy:

- `std::launch::async`, means that the function must be run asynchronously, i.e, on a different thread.
- `std::launch::deferred`, means that the function may run only when `get` or `wait` is called on the future return by `std::async`. When `get` or `wait` is invoked, the function will execute synchronously. The caller of the function will be blocks until the fucntion finish running. If `get` or `wait`
  is not invoked, then the function will never run.

```
auto future1 = std::async(my_function); // run my_function using defautl launch policy
auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred) // run my_function either async or defered
```

Refered from the book "Effective Modern C++" by Scoot Meyers, item 36: Specify std::launch ::async if  asynchronicity is essential.

If parallel computing is what you need, you may consider using [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/).

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: Does this work for classes as well? I would like to put one instance of a class on one single process the entire execution of the program. Then I would like to call member function on each class.

Comment: You can pass `std::async` with [fucntion object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/function-objects-in-the-stl?view=vs-2019), however, you cann't pass normal class object to `std::async`. You may write your own class to wrap C++ ConcurrencyAPI to accompolish putting one instance of a class on one single process the entire execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe help you.

```
class test_thread_instanse
{
     public:
     void operator()(int x)
     {
         std::cout << "test" <<x <<  std::endl;
     }
};
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(test_thread_instanse(), 1);
    std::thread t2(test_thread_instanse(), 2);
    std::thread t3(test_thread_instanse(), 3);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return(0);

 }
```